# Passing multiple exclude with PSWindowsUpdate

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been trying to exclude  multiple title for PSWindowsUpdate module. But I am getting an error message like below.

```
$Exclude = @("SharePoint","SQL Server")
Get-WUlist -MicrosoftUpdate -UpdateType Software -NotTitle $Exclude -Verbose
```

or

```
Get-WUlist -MicrosoftUpdate -UpdateType Software -NotTitle "SharePoint", "SQL Server" -Verbose
```

Error:

```
Get-WindowsUpdate : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'NotTitle'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:2 char:60
+ ... list -MicrosoftUpdate -UpdateType Software -NotTitle $Exclude -Verbos ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate
```

Comment: as stated in the error message, the paramter -notTile does not support an array as input. You can only pass a string. The command uses the following statement for the parameter: `If($Update.Title -match $NotTitle)`. So it is no possible with that parameter to achieve what you try. You should pipe the result and use where-object to filter your result